# How to remove html tags from fullcalendar title version 2

Tags: fullcalendar

Hi I'm using FullCalendar v2.2.3

When I'm adding my html into my description it's populating the html in the title. I'd like it to use the html instead of plain text.

```
<p>testing testing</p>
<p>test</p>
```

[this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPIhS.jpg)

Comment: you'd have to use the eventRender callback to modify it. By default fullCalendar treats your description as text. Sensible protection against things like script injection.

Comment: I've seen that answer around. I don't know what that means. I'm just the project manager and not the developer. I know a decent amount, but not where to add what you're saying.

Comment: can you show the existing calendar code please?

Comment: I don't have access to the code...it's okay I guess I'll simply be able to give my developer direction on this. Can you tell me if it's not safe to update the code? Are they going to be at risk of being script injection after my dev updates the code?

Comment: Shouldn't be, because it's your code that's creating the HTML and wrapping the description within it, rather than just accepting whatever's entered into the database and rendering it blindly.

Comment: BTW, you asked about an example of how/where to use the eventRender function, there's a fairly clear one in the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/